# Вопрос по специфике статического класса

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, static

Привет всем.

О том как работает ключевое слово *static* представление имею.
Заморочился и пытаюсь понять для чего нужны статические классы и как статический класс работает при наследовании + вот эта ситуация недопонятна (начну вопросы с нее):

```
class Str2 {
public:
    static int b;
};
int Str2::b = 0;

void main() {
    Str2::b = 9;
}
```

Пример выше работает, но если закоментировать *int Str2::b = 0;*, то пример становится нерабочим:
*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static int Str2::b" (?b@Str2@@2HA)  Test_1  C:\Users\Sergey\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Test_1\Test_1\main.obj    1*   Почему? Почему статическую переменную нужно инициализировать под классом перед ее первым использованием?

В C# есть статический конструктор, int Str2::b = 0; - это аналог статического конструктора??? Понимаю, что имени конструктора тут нигде нет, но функция та же?

Теперь пример ближе к делу:

```
static class Str1 {
public: 
    int a;
};
//int Str1::a = 8;

class Str2 : public Str1 {
public:
    static int b;
};
int Str2::b = 0;

void main() {
    Str1::a = 9;
}
```

В данном случае и класс Str1 static. Раз класс static, то и переменная *a* должна быть static, разве нет? На сколько я понял, static - это то, что не наследуется. Логично, что класс Str1 при наследовании наследовал бы свои поля и методы как static (то есть просто разрешал бы доступ к static-ам), но нет. Мои эксперименты показали, что Str1 наследовался как обычный класс.

Будет ли разница в вариантах наследования (static/не static)?  :

```
    static class Str1 {
    public: 
        int a;
    };

    static class NoStatic {
    public: 
        int a;
    };

    class Str2 : public **Str1/NoStatic** {
    };
```

Comment: @rdorn: А зачем вы удалили ответ?

Comment: @VladD пусть автор сначала определится с языком.

Comment: @rdorn: Ну, в C++ вроде вовсе нету статических классов. Так что я начал бы с упоминания этого факта, и дальше говорил только про C#.

Comment: Мой вопрос по языку С++.

Comment: @VladD, если в С++ нет статических классов, то почему такое работает: static class ClassName{} ?

Comment: @Alerr: Компилирую ваш код, получаю: warning C4091: 'static ': ignored on left of 'ClassName' when no variable is declared

Comment: @VladD, спасибо.

Comment: @Alerr: Пожалуйста! Вот ещё по теме: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9321/276994